# How to create multiple instances of a feature in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a time tracking app in AngularJS simply to learn the framework. I'm attempting to create the ability to add multiple timers within a single view by clicking an 'add' button. Each timer would obviously contain unique properties and unique methods for the timing functionality. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how I can set up a service to do such a thing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Based on whatever little detail you have provided, you can create angular directive with isolated scope to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: @Chandermani That's what I'm working on now - thanks. Once I've created the directive, how would I then duplicate it via user interaction? Sorry for the lack of extensive detail. Detail regarding this topic is sort of the crux of my question after all. Is there a particular aspect of the question that I can explain further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Chandermani has mentioned, you should wrap your timer within a directive. This should get you started:

**Javascript**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.timers = [];
})
.directive('timer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E', 
    template: '<h1>{{counter}}s</h1>',
    controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
      $scope.counter = 0;

      var callback = function() {
        $scope.counter++;
        $timeout(callback, 1000);
      };

      $timeout(callback, 1000);
    }
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="timers.push(1)">Add timer</button>
    <timer ng-repeat="timer in timers"></timer>
</body>
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wbx4jTRwNtN7jeOA1Va9).

The `ng-repeat` directive will render one instance of the `timer` directive for each item in the `timers` array. In this contrived example, that array has no purpose whatsoever besides controlling how many timers exist at a time. You could use it to store any information you might have about each timer individually.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBenford - this will indeed get me started!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a control that manages a list of timers

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.controller('TimerCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.timers = [];
  $scope.addTimer = function() {
    $scope.timers.push(new TaskTimer());
  };
  /* additional remove/clear/whatever functions attach to $scope */
});
```

Code example: http://jsfiddle.net/bonza_labs/qvnNa/

The "timer" object in the code example is something you would want to write yourself, so I've just stubbed it out with an object that doesn't actually do anything. As suggested, directives are a nice way to wrap up the rendering of the timers.